# Parse Json Data in wcf Rest?

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf

I want to create a WCF rest service which accept a json data and parse all value.

My json data coming from client side like this:

```
{"user":{"UserName":"123","Pass":"123"}}
```

i create a simple wcf OperationContract :

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "Login",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
          )]
        string Login(User user);
```

what can i do in this login method for parsing the json data??

Comment: Does this work? Have you tried it? What response do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send data from your client like this:

```
{"UserName":"123","Pass":"123"}
```

You have to like this class

```
class User{

public string Username {get;set;}
public string Pass {get;set;}
}
```

If your client insist on this request :

```
{"user":{"UserName":"123","Pass":"123"}},
```

You should be have like this class:

```
class User{

public string Username {get;set;}
public string Pass {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
class RequestJ{
public User user{get;set;}
}
```

---

And you must change your wcf service like this :

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "Login",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
          )]
        string Login(RequestJ user);
```